# Reading file to the 2d array efficently

Tags: c++, vector, hpc

I have two big files one `int` and the other `float`. I want to store them in a 2d `vector`.

What is the fastest way to read such a data.

Note: the number of  element in each row is unique in the entire document.

What I did?

```
std::string temp;
std::ifstream infile(Path);
int i=0;
std::vector<std::vector<float> data(100, std::vector<float>(1000));
while (std::getline(infile, temp))
    {
        std::istringstream buffer(temp);
        int j = 0;
        while (!buffer.eof())
        {
            float temp2;
            buffer >> temp2;
            if (buffer.fail())
            {
                throw "Undefined variable in the input file!";
            }

                data.at(i).at(j) = temp2;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

This code is very slow!

Comment: does your code even work? you are indexing `data` but I dont see you set its size anywhere

Comment: data(100, std::vector<float>(1000)). added.

Comment: You're still missing a declaration & initialization of `i`.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of elements (and rows) is unique, you can't use pre-sized vectors and indexing.
Not only will it break if there are more elements than you thought, all the elements you don't replace will be zero (or empty).

Instead, start with empty vectors and use `push_back`.
To avoid reallocation of the vectors, you can use `reserve` first.

Something like this:

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream infile(Path);
std::vector<std::vector<float>> data;
data.reserve(100);  // Assuming no more than 100 lines

while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    data.emplace_back();
    std::vector<float>& row = data.back();
    row.reserve(1000); // Assuming 1000 elements will do
    std::istringstream buffer(line);
    float element = 0;
    while (buffer >> element)
    {
        row.push_back(element);
    }
}
```

If you want to read as fast as possible, don't use a text format for your data.

Answer (score 1):

Few hints,

1. disable stdio sync by adding :

   ```
   std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
   ```

at the top of your code.

2. Reuse your std::istringstream, put:

   ```
   std::istringstream buffer(temp);
   ```

outside your loops, and after using it clear it with `buffer.clear();`

3. Instead of:

   ```
   data.at(i).at(j) = temp2;
   ```

use:

```
data[i][j] = temp2;
```

this version does not check bounds so its slightly faster.

Comment: I do not know how the unix command are extremely fast and efficient. For example although I used your suggestion, the disk usage did not change. When I am reading from disk, I expected disk usage not cpu usage. What is the bottleneck?